# Bachelor vs Bachelor's

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, academia

I am not a native speaker, but I noticed that sometimes people use Bachelor or Bachelor's in some context, although I don't understand the difference:

See for instance also this question [click me](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67188/bachelor-thesis-or-bachelors-thesis)

For instance I would call myself a Bachelor student, but do I do my Bachelor's studies or my Bachelor studies?

Actually, I don't understand the difference between Bachelor and Bachelor's and I don't know when to use one or the other. Could anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "I am a Bachelor," most modern English speakers will interpret this as saying that you are an unmarried man.  (Aside: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor) is interesting background). If you add "student" to the end, you will probably not be misunderstood, but it would be more common to phrase this as "I am working on (a/my) Bachelor's (degree/program/study)."

As to whether to use the apostrophe-s, consider these examples:

- This is a cat toy. (a toy *intended for use by* a cat.)
- This is a cat's toy. (a toy *possessed by* a cat.)

Notice that both work grammatically, and have very similar meaning.  Likewise:

- I am working on a Bachelor degree (a degree *designed around* a lower-level student)
- I am working on a Bachelor's degree (a degree *earned by* a lower-level student)

The difference is subtle, and most listeners will not consider it important.